# How do dynamically ad div with <script>tag including inline JS so that this JS executes?

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I am having an issue trying to dynamically add and execute a div containing inline Javascript?

```
var div = document.createElement('DIV');                
div.onready = (function(name) { return GA_vitalFillSlot(name); })(wallpaper_ads.custom[i]);
document.getElementById('wallpaperAdContainer').appendChild(div);
```

where `wallpaper_ads.custom[i]` contains a string, e.g. 'BMX_wallpaper_2328x1080_homepage'.
Above code does not work. But it works if I change `GA_vitalFillSlot()` to `alert()`:

```
var div = document.createElement('DIV');                
div.onready = (function(name) { return alert(name); })(wallpaper_ads.custom[i]);
document.getElementById('wallpaperAdContainer').appendChild(div);
```

Also, doing something like this doesn't work either:

```
var js = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
js.type = 'text/javascript';
js.innerHTML = 'GA_vitalFillSlot("'+wallpaper_ads.custom[i]+'");';
document.getElementById('wallpaperAdContainer').appendChild(js);
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
js.src = 'myCode.js';
```

or

```
js.text = 'alert("hey");';
```

Script inserted using innerHTML does not get executed.

Comment: I don't have source of Google DFP code for GA_googleFillSlot() so I can't use it. I can only try to execute function that's already been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code:

`(function(name) { return GA_vitalFillSlot(name); })(wallpaper_ads.custom[i]);`

is executing immediately setting the `div.onready` equal to the result of `GA_vitalFillSlot(name)`. Change it so the onready points to a function:

```
div.onready = (function(name) { 
    return function() {
        GA_vitalFillSlot(name);
    };
})(wallpaper_ads.custom[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
js.src = 'GA_vitalFillSlot("'+wallpaper_ads.custom[i]+'");';
```